# "Go-To" or "Jump" action in SharePoint Workflow Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a "Jump" action in SharePoint Designer 2010 when building workflows?

For example:

```
If No Approver 1
    Jump to "JumpHere"
Else 
    E-mail Approver 1
    Wait for Approval

   If Approved
      Jump to "JumpHere"
   Else 
      Notify Requestor he's been rejected.

"JumpHere"
If No Approver 2
    Jump to "JumpHere2"
Else
   E-mail Approver 2
   Wait for Approval

   If Approved
      Jump to "JumpHere2"
   Else 
      Notify Requestor he's been rejected.

"JumpHere2"
Repeat...
```

I used jumping all the time when writing in MIPS assembly, but can't seem to use it with this... But really need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope I don't believe so. If you have a set of actions that may repeat, you will basically have to add them each time after your condition. Yes this will cause a bit of 'duplicate code' but the workflows are more for non programmers so they set it up to be ran in order from step 1 to step 2 to step 3, etc.

You could, however write the workflows in C# (If you know it well enough) and do what you are asking

Comment: haha, I knew you were going to suggest Visual Studio. My boss won't let me code it because he wants non-coders to be able to easily edit the workflow so they don't have to rely on me for maintenance. No Jumps, no loops, no nothing...Stupid SharePoint designer... oh well. Thanks though :)

Comment: please describe more about your solution. we could have condition in any steps. and check flags and variables like machine state or state-machine in compilers. are you solve this by opening wsp file of SharePoint workflow in VS?